# Firebase phone number authentication vertification failed

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android

I used the codes on this link. It worked fine on the three phones but I keep getting a "verification failed" error on a phone and it does not come in the message for verification code.

Comment: Two questions: a) did you use the same phone number as those succeeded on other devices? b) have you checked log what's the error code you get back? The sample app logs a warning when onVerificationFailed

Comment: I used the phone number of each person on each phone. The phone number on the phone where the entry failed is the SMS I tried on other devices and the entry was made.

Comment: How about b)? What error did you get?

Comment: I am getting the error code 39 with message An Internal error has occurred. [Error code 39]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have enabled the *phone auth authentication*  from 
 *sign in methods* tab inside Firebase Console Authentication section

Answer (score 1):

For the verification Failed issue;

**Try adding SHA-1 or SHA-256 or Both Certificates in your Firebase Project Settings.**

To get the certificate (Android Studio) : Gradle (:app) -> Tasks -> android -> signingReport

Firebase Console : Project Settings -> SDK setup and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are entering the country code with a plus (+) sign,  with the number.